# Drawdown distribution mentioned in Expert Trading Systems (John Wolberg)

Tags: probability, quantitative, investment, maximum-drawdown, drawdown

In equation 2.13 of Chapter 2 (pg. 41), in his book "Expert Trading Systems: modeling financial markets with kernel regression," John Wolberg writes the probability of drawdown of $P$ percentage units or greater as $(1-\frac{P}{100})^\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are the first and second central moments of a Gaussian process for returns.

There is no run-up to this statement, only a reference (in the footnotes) to a private communication by P. Feigin, which I am unable to find online.

Bouchaud et al. obtain a density function for the drawdown, in equation 13 of "You are in a drawdown. When should you start worrying?" (link https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01457.pdf). However, this is expressed as a fearsome marginal distribution, integrating out the drawdown length, and I wonder if it will lead to the Wolberg survival function. I am unable to coax it there.

Zhong and Maslov in "Probability distribution of drawdowns in risky investments" (link https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9808295.pdf) as far as I can understand, show that the density function for the same process is $f(x)=\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}e^{\frac{-2\mu}{\sigma^2}x}$. Again, I cannot relate this to Wolberg's result,since $\int_\frac{P}{100}^\infty f(x).dx=e^{-\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}(\frac{P}{100})}$.

My questions are: (1) can anyone help me reconcile all three statements, please? and (2) how does Wolberg get there? the other two articles are adequately clear in development.